# Error in Android studio java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, filenotfoundexception

I got error when I want to debbuging usb at my phone I cant display my code on android studio in my phone and the error looks like this: please help me I am using android  studio 2.0 and my phone is ASUS Fone-Pad 8.0.

Error:java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Andrezs\AndroidStudioProjects\HappySunday.gradle\2.10\taskArtifacts\cache.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)

> C:\Users\Andrezs\AndroidStudioProjects\HappySunday.gradle\2.10\taskArtifacts\cache.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: Do you know the mean of File not Found ?

Comment: I think this FNF exception is not usual like try to access a file on sd card or something. I guess you have moved your properties file into a wrong folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio Java File Not Found Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49078660/android-studio-java-file-not-found-exception)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read the Android Studio 2.0 changes doc.
because adding some new functionality in Android Studio and its effect on some another functions.
So, Read the Documentation and issues pages and You can solve this problem.

As my opinion , this type of error found When your app run in Instant Run feature of Android Studio. so, new build not generated every time and app content not found in your android device.

**Solution** is define in [this link](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/instant-run) or following instruction :

```html
<div><p style="margin:0px 0px 12px;font-family:Roboto,sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:24px"><font color="#000000">By default, Android Studio automatically restarts the current activity after performing a hot swap, while the app keeps running. To disable this setting:</font></p><ol style="margin:0px 0px 15px 20px;padding:0px;font-family:Roboto,sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:24px"><li style="margin:0px 0px 12px"><font color="#000000">Open the&nbsp;<strong>Settings</strong>&nbsp;or&nbsp;<strong>Preferences</strong>&nbsp;dialog.</font></li><li style="margin:0px 0px 12px"><font color="#000000">Navigate to&nbsp;<strong>Build, Execution, Deployment</strong>&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;<strong>Instant Run.</strong></font></li><li style="margin:0px 0px 12px"><font color="#000000">Uncheck the box next to&nbsp;<strong>Restart activity on code changes</strong>.</font></li></ol><p style="margin:0px 0px 12px;font-family:Roboto,sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:24px"><font color="#000000">If automatic activity restart is disabled, you can manually restart the current activity from the menu bar by selecting&nbsp;<strong>Run</strong>&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;<strong>Restart Activity</strong>.</font></p><h4 style="font-size:18px;line-height:24px;margin:12px 0px;font-family:Roboto,sans-serif"><a name="TOC-Using-Rerun"></a><font color="#000000">Using Rerun</font></h4><p style="margin:0px 0px 12px;font-family:Roboto,sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:24px"><font color="#000000">When pushing certain code changes, such as changes to an app's&nbsp;<code style="font-size:13px;font-stretch:normal;line-height:18px;font-family:Consolas,Liberation Mono,Menlo,Courier,monospace;padding:3px 5px;background-color:rgb(247,247,247)"><a href="http://adarshf-linux.kir.corp.google.com:9000/reference/android/app/Application.html#onCreate()" style="text-decoration:none">onCreate()</a></code>&nbsp;method, you will need to restart your running app for the changes to take effect. You can click&nbsp;<strong>Rerun&nbsp;</strong></font><img border="0" src="http://tools.android.com/_/rsrc/1458888270801/tech-docs/instant-run/as-restart.png"><strong style="color:rgb(0,0,0);background-color:transparent">&nbsp;</strong><span style="color:rgb(0,0,0);background-color:transparent">to stop the app, perform an&nbsp;</span><em style="color:rgb(0,0,0);background-color:transparent">incremental build</em><span style="color:rgb(0,0,0);background-color:transparent">, and restart the app.</span></p><p style="margin:0px 0px 12px;font-family:Roboto,sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:24px"><font color="#000000">If you need to deploy a&nbsp;<em>clean build</em>, select&nbsp;<strong>Run</strong>&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;<strong>Clean and Rerun 'app'</strong>&nbsp;</font><img border="0" src="http://tools.android.com/_/rsrc/1458888258422/tech-docs/instant-run/as-cleanrerun.png"><font color="#000000">&nbsp;from the main menu, or hold down the&nbsp;<strong>Shift</strong>&nbsp;key while clicking&nbsp;<strong>Rerun</strong>&nbsp;</font><img border="0" src="http://tools.android.com/_/rsrc/1458888270801/tech-docs/instant-run/as-restart.png"><font color="#000000">. This action stops the running app, performs a full clean build, and deploys the new APK to your target device.</font></p></div>
```

If above solution not worked than go to **project** > **app** folder > **build** folder and delete build folder than after run again.

Answer (score 3):

Quit Android Studio, delete build folder, open your project again. Should fix the problem.

Answer (score 3):

go to the project and delete .idea,.gradle & build folder from project and then import the project