# Android Studio Java File Not Found Exception

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

I tried every possible combination of paths that i could think of along with every possible location of the file. It simply does not stop going for the file Not Found exception (No file or Directory)

```
  try {
        String path = "D:\\Users\\[UserName]\\Desktop\\[NameofProject]\\app\\src\\main\\assets\\itemsURL";
        FileReader fileP = new FileReader(path);
        BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(fileP);
        for(String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; ) {
            filesArray.add(line);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
```

Has anyone ever got this problem of, possibly, the most stubborn File Not Found exception?

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Users\UserName]\Desktop\[NameofProject]\app\src\main\assets\itemsURL (No such file or directory)
```

File Format is like this:

```
 algae_banana
 boop_boop
 word_word_word
 bla_bla
 ...
```

Comment: perhaps you are missing the file extension? itemsURL.txt or  itemsURL.rtf  or itemsURL.csv  etc??

Comment: Nope, tried again with it and without and decided to add .txt to the end of the file and even went with itemsURL.txt.txt in the code after adding it. Still the same.

Comment: what kind of file is it? adding .txt to the end of the file name doesn't make it visible if the file itself is not a .txt file.

Comment: It's a file with a string in format of word_word in each line, no commas or any other symbol. Added it to problem description above.

Comment: if you were to search for the file on your computer it would show what kind of file it is. If you are using windows, search the name "itemsURL", once found right click the file and select properties, it should display the type of file it is. I am not asking about the contents of the file.

Comment: Yes it's a .txt file.

Comment: Now just paste the location of the file in the properties drop down and and append your file's name to it

Comment: Thanks mate but already got it working I was looking at it the wrong way in terms of windows to android path location.

Comment: well i'm glad you were able to get it resolved! keep on coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how it works. You run the app on an emulator and there is no path D:/users/... on an android Device.

Try using he Assets folder and the getAssetManager()

Comment: That's what I was kind of thinking but had no idea how to do, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Thank you, got it working by creating a decent asset folder and then using  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("itemsURL")));

The problem here is that before I had tried doing it only by writing the name of the file and I thought the management of files was done automatically and since it wasn't working the problem could've been elsewhere.